# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS freezes when printing to HP OfficeJet 8710

Tags: 16.04, printing, hp

I've had this HP OfficeJet 8710 printer for several months and it was working fine until a couple of days ago. Every time I print a document, whether it is a pdf, .docx, or .odt, the computer (an HP Slimline Desktop 270-a016) sends the file, printer starts printing, and then computer completely freezes (printer continues to print and finishes the job, but computer is completely frozen). No mouse, no keyboard, nothing. Have to manually power off the computer and restart. Sometimes when I restart (not every time though) the printer automatically starts printing the last job again, which causes the computer to freeze before I can even log in.  I've updated to the latest hplip file, fixed CUPS permission error, and I've run hp-doctor and hp-check, both of which say there are no errors or warnings. At this point, I'm at a loss and don't know what else to try. Thanks in advance for your time and advice!

UPDATE: I upgraded to 18.04. Printer installed no problem (way easier, in fact, that in 16.04), but problem persists. I also thought it might be something with gutenprint and the spooling, so I uninstalled those packages. That actually worked for two documents, but then the next day the problem started up again and still persists. Any ideas what could possibly be causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you install `hplip-gui` and then uninstall printer and reinstall using the `hplip-gui` (it's called '**hp toolbox**' in the menu.)

Comment: Printer is connected via USB. I'll give your suggestion a try, thanks so much for the idea!

Comment: Just tried your suggestion and it's working! No idea what was wrong or why this works, but thanks SO much!!

Comment: @anax2510 If you find this answer useful, please consider ["accepting" it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking the tick (✓) next to it) to indicate you've found a working solution and also so that others may more easily find it in the future.